# Why do I need to create a new instance of a Line instead of simply update or add and remove it in Kivy

Tags: kivy

I am attempting to draw a line with the mouse by dragging from one point to another point of the window. I also want to represent the line while I am dragging. Like drawing a line in an old MS PaintBrush.

My problem is that I have only been able to achieve this by constantly removing the old Line and adding a **new** Vertex Instruction to the canvas. However, I cannot update existing instructions. Not even adding and removing the same instruction. It has to be a new instance of Line. You can see the result that I want by running the following code. If you try to run it with the commented lines it doesn't work any more.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line

class MyCanvas(RelativeLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = Line(points=[touch.x,touch.y,touch.x+1,touch.y+1])
        self.bind(on_touch_move=self.update_line, on_touch_up=self.end_line)
        return True

    def update_line(self, instance, touch):
        self.line.points[2] = touch.x
        self.line.points[3] = touch.y
        self.canvas.remove(self.line)
#        self.canvas.add(self.line) # - this doesn't work
#        self.canvas.ask_update()   # - not even using this
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = Line(points=self.line.points) # this works

    def end_line(self, instance, touch):
        self.unbind(on_touch_move=self.update_line)
        self.unbind(on_touch_up=self.end_line)
        self.line.points[2] = touch.x
        self.line.points[3] = touch.y
        self.canvas.remove(self.line)
#        self.canvas.add(self.line) # - this doesn't work
#        self.canvas.ask_update()   #- not even using this
        self.canvas.add(Line(points=self.line.points))  # this way works

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyCanvas()

ExampleApp().run()
```

I also tried using Kivy properties as suggested [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997545/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-widget-in-kivy-at-run-time) with the Color instruction. It didn't work and there is [another question related to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997545/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-widget-in-kivy-at-run-time).

Comment: I dig into the code with `ipdb` and I realize that the there is a Line'attribute called needs_redraw. It is always False in the current Line and the variable is write protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling with the same problem. I started from the 6_button.py example from the kivy/guide/firstwidget directory

I found something that works (using pop twice to remove the last x,y pair from points) But I think it is very awkward, see my code below. I hope someone can tel us how to 'update' properly.

## based on 6_button.py

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 10.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y, touch.x+30, touch.y))
            #print(dir(touch.ud['line']))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        #touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
        touch.ud['line'].points.pop()                     #
        touch.ud['line'].points.pop()                     # works but is awkward
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]     #

        #touch.ud['line'].points[2:4] = [touch.x, touch.y] 
        #self.canvas.ask_update()              # no error but didnt work
        #touch.ud['line'].ask_update()         # didnt work
        #print(touch.ud['line'].points)
        #touch.ud['line'].needs_redraw()       # error 'bool not callable'
        #touch.ud['line'].needs_redraw = True  # error 'not writable'
        #touch.ud['line'].needs_redraw         #no error but doesnt work


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)

        def clear_canvas(obj):
            painter.canvas.clear()
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=clear_canvas)

        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: It is not that awkward. It doesn't explain why the direct assign doesn't work `self.line.points[2] = touch.x` though. I was started to think that the only way creating a new instance but you found another way. I can tell you that this will fail if you are updating `pos`  for an `Ellipse` because it is a `tuple`  and there is no `pop` method. Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058098/how-do-i-update-the-color-of-a-dynamically-added-ellipse-not-using-builder) that was answered by a Kivy developer. Creating a new Line might not be that wrong after all.