# Change button or label text color in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm following [this kivy book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9781783281596), and while I can understand how to change the background color of buttons, I haven't found the keyword to change the text color.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181250/changing-the-background-color-of-a-button-in-kivy) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997545/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-widget-in-kivy-at-run-time) questions.  Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle

class MinimalApp(App):
    title = 'My App'
    def build(self):
        root = RootLayout()
        return(root)

class RootLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MinimalApp().run()
```

## and in the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.7.2
#:import kivy kivy

<RootLayout>:
    rows: 1
    Label:
        text: "Why does this not work?"
#        rgba: 1,0,1,1                  # doesn't work
#        Color:                         # doesn't work
#                rgba: 1,0,1,1          # doesn't work
#       font_color: rgba: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`color`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.color) (all lowercase):

```
<RootLayout>:
    rows: 1
    Label:
        text: "Why does this not work?"
        color: 1,0,1,1 # <-----------
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Comment: If you run into trouble with this answer, it's probably the implementation of the canvas object.  Take notice that @falsetru calls "canvas.before" event, not plain old "canvas:"

Answer (score 0):

in python, you just need to add an argument named "color" and assign to it a tuple of rgba value.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItVNd.png)