# Python Kivy - change Label color

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Is there a way to change the `background_color` of a `Label` without using canvas?

As i run the code, the background color is automaticlly black...

Here is my simple code:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyWindow(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        label = Label(text='Hello World')
        box.add_widget(label)
        return box

window = MyWindow()

window.run()
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button or label text color in kivy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437728/change-button-or-label-text-color-in-kivy)

Comment: @WhiteShadow Not a duplicate, OP asks if there's a different way as in the that question :P

Answer (score 0):

Background color by itself, no. You'll still need to change it inside another widget or something similar. But if you use a picture of one color, then it is!

`Label` doesn't have a background by itself, that's why you can use its `canvas` to put it there, otherwise it's transparent. If it's transparent, that means it can show a content of another widget e.g. the one that's under it.

So put under it `Image` and you have basically the whole `canvas` + `Rectangle` with `source` thing, but separated into two widgets. If you want to change only background color, open e.g. `mspaint`, fill it with a single color and load with Python.

It might not work with `BoxLayout` correctly, because it handles position of its children automatically, but with `FloatLayout` that's not a problem anymore:

```
from kivy.app import App    
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        flt = FloatLayout()
        image = Image(size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300),
                      source=<path to image>)
        label = Label(size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300),
                      text='Hello World')
        flt.add_widget(image)
        flt.add_widget(label)
        return flt

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: naming an App class `MyWindow`, and its instance `window` may confuse the hell out of people :P