# Change text color in Python Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm currently programming on a Kivy Project. To make it look better I would like to know how to change the text color of a button.
The button is supposed to be white at the end with black text, however I just can't find a solution on the internet.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437728/change-button-or-label-text-color-in-kivy) looks like it answers yours.

Answer (score 0):

On a .kv file, you would just do:

```
Label:
    text: 'Blah Blah Blah'
    color: 1, 0, 1, 1
```

On a .py file, you would just do:

```
def __init__(self):
    #don't forget the super()
    self.label = Label(text='BlahBlahBlah', color=(1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.add_widget(self.label)
```