# Kivy: Updating colour of widgets in real time

Tags: python, python-2.7, drawing, kivy

I found this similar question:

[How do I change the color of my widget in Kivy at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997545/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-widget-in-kivy-at-run-time)

I'm using a similar approach to try and change the colour of widgets as I drag and move them around.

---

```
class GraphNode(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1.0)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.size= [50,50]
    self.pos = [175,125]
    super(GraphNode, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        if touch.grab_current == None:
            self.r = 0.6
            touch.grab(self)             
            return True                
    return super(GraphNode, self).on_touch_down(touch)



def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is self:
        self.pos=[touch.x-25,touch.y-25]
    # now we only handle moves which we have grabbed


def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is self:
        touch.ungrab(self)
        self.r = 1.0
        # and finish up here


def onTouchMove(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        self.pos=[touch.x-25, touch.y-25]
pass
```

---

I'm trying to update the numeric property to change the color, using this (kv) file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<GraphInterface>:
    node: graph_node

    GraphNode:
        id: graph_node
        center: self.parent.center

<GraphApp>:
    canvas:

<GraphNode>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: (root.r,1,1,1)

<GraphEdge>:
    size: 10, 10
    canvas:
```

However the colours do not change when I grab them. If I don't change the colour in the on_touch_drop() method, then i can spawn nodes with the new colour. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code probably works fine, but the Color instruction is after everything else and so simply doesn't affect anything. Did you mean to put it before the Ellipse?

Comment: I still don't entirely understand all this Kivy stuff, but this has fixed my issue. Thanks!